# Terraform count within for_each loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create GCP SQL DBs by iterating a list of string using Terraform's **for_each** and **count** parameter and the other loop is for the map keys (**maindb** & **replicadb**).

Unfortunately, I get the error that appears below.

Is it possible to do this is Terraform?

**variables.tf**

```
variable "sql_var" {
    default = {
        "maindb" = {
            "db_list" = ["firstdb", "secondsdb", "thirddb"],
            "disk_size" = "20",
        },
        "replicadb" = {
            "db_list" = ["firstdb"],
            "disk_size" = "",
        }
    }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master_sql_instance" {
...
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  for_each = var.sql_var
  name =  "${element(each.value.db_list, count.index)}"
  instance = "${google_sql_database_instance.master_sql_instance[each.key].name}"

  count =  "${length(each.value.db_list)}"
}
```

**Error Message**

> Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
>
> on ../main.tf line 43, in resource
> "google_sql_database" "database":   43:   for_each =
> var.sql_var
>
> The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only
> one should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be
> created.

Answer (score 0):

What the error message tells you is that you cannot use count and for_each together. It looks like you are trying to create 3 main databases and 1 replica database am I correct? What I would do is create your 2 master instances and then transform your map variable to create the databases.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.13.3"

  required_providers {
    google = ">=3.36.0"
  }
}

variable "sql_instances" {
  default = {
    "main_instance" = {
      "db_list"   = ["first_db", "second_db", "third_db"],
      "disk_size" = "20",
    },
    "replica_instance" = {
      "db_list"   = ["first_db"],
      "disk_size" = "20",
    }
  }
}

locals {
  databases = flatten([
    for key, value in var.sql_instances : [
      for item in value.db_list : {
        name     = item
        instance = key
      }
    ]
  ])
  sql_databases = {
    for item in local.databases :
    uuid() => item
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql_instance" {
  for_each = var.sql_instances
  name     = each.key

  settings {
    disk_size = each.value.disk_size
    tier      = "db-f1-micro"
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "sql_database" {
  for_each = local.sql_databases
  name     = each.value.name
  instance = each.value.instance

  depends_on = [
    google_sql_database_instance.sql_instance,
  ]
}
```

Then, first run `terraform apply -target=google_sql_database_instance.sql_instance` and after this run `terraform apply`.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well. let my try again :)
I'd like to iterate the variable "sql_var" keys (maindb, replicadb) using for_each loop and within each of this keys I want to get the length of the list var "db_list" and execute the resource "google_sql_database.database" n times.
In the end I want to get - GCP SQL instance named "maindb" with 3 dbs inside "firstdb", "secondsdb", "thirddb"

Comment: The above should work. I created a list of databases, which should all be created with a reference to the instance they belong to. And they should only be created after the instance is created. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I've tried to run terraform plan but I got this error = 
"Error: Invalid for_each argument"

on ../main.tf line 59, in resource "google_sql_database" "database": for_each = local.sql_databases
The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.

Comment: Yes, it still does not work. I get this error on the resource "google_sql_database.sql_database"
Error: Invalid for_each argument

Comment: This is a common error in terraform, you should then first apply the instances only, and then apply the rest of the terraform configuration.

Comment: I tried running the terraform apply first but it did not resolve the issue and I still get the same error message for the same resource (for_each = local.sql_databases) (Error: Invalid for_each argument) -